# SSIS package to import a comma separate flat file with a column containing commas

Tags: ssis

SSIS package to import a flat file. one of the columns in this file source is called StreetAddress and contains address details, however some of the address parts in this column are separated with commas. Below I have pasted the column names and 2 records. first one doesn't have any problem but for the second one there is an extra comma within the address. I have highlighted the same.

i know i have to use Conditional Splits and Derived Columns but couldn't figure out which condition should i use here. due to this street address i get wrong data in City,  StateProvinceCode etc.. what condition should i use to separate this and use derived column?

```
CustomerKey, CustomerAlternateKey, FirstName, MiddleInitial, LastName, MaritalStatus, Gender, DateOfBirth, PhoneNumber, StreetAddress, City, StateProvinceCode, StateProvinceName, CountryCode, CountryName, PostCode
12311, AW00012311, Stanley, E, Weber, S, M, 1954-06-19,1 (11) 500 555-0133,7859 Green Valley Road, London, ENG, England, GB, United Kingdom, W1V 5RN
12312, AW00012312, Jake, R, Zhao, M, M, 1953-11-10,1 (11) 500 555-0192, 454, boulevard Tremblay , Paris, 75, Seine (Paris), FR, France, 75007
```

Comment: request a quote wrapped csv is your easiest solution or change delimter to something not in the text like a |. Also, the are not normally spaces in a csv